# FlexPrintJob giving error inside Interactive PDF

Tags: pdf, interactive, flash-builder4.5

I created a swf file in Adobe FlashBuilder 4.6 web version and I want interactive PDF. I successfully embed this swf inside PDF with the help of java iText PDF library.
My problem is when I click a print button it gives below error

Error #2057: The page could not be added to the print job.
at Error$/throwError()
at flash.printing::PrintJob/addPage()

My code is

private function doPrint(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

```
            var printJob:FlexPrintJob = new FlexPrintJob();

                 if(printJob.start())
                {
                    var thePrintView:FormPrintView = new FormPrintView();
                    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addElement(thePrintView);

                    thePrintView.width=printJob.pageWidth;
                    thePrintView.height=printJob.pageHeight;

                    thePrintView.padg.dataProvider = allGrid.dataProvider;
                    printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                    thePrintView.pageNumber++;
                    while(true) {
                        thePrintView.padg.nextPage();
                        if (!thePrintView.padg.validNextPage) {
                            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            printJob.addObject(thePrintView);
                            thePrintView.pageNumber++;
                        }
                    }
                    FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.removeElement(thePrintView);
                }
                printJob.send(); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially solved. If I use Adobe acrobat reader 11 then error is comeing but useing 
Adobe acrobat reader 10.1 error is not comeing.